# gRPC server authentication with windows user

Tags: .net, windows, authentication, grpc, http2

I'm working on a gRPC web application in C#, and I'm trying to restrict access to the server so that only a specific Windows user (one of the users in the C:\Users directory) can make requests to it. I'm wondering what steps I need to take to achieve this.

Does anyone have experience with this or can provide some guidance on how to implement user authentication in gRPC with Windows user accounts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been stumped by this problem as well. The following suggests that gRPC cannot support Windows authentication, given that it uses HTTP/2: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/409